# Why does creating a bucket with Terraform throw "The provider provider.aws does not support resource type "aws_s3"" error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to create an S3 bucket using the following terraform code:

provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "XX"
  secret_key = "YY"
  region = "us-east-2"
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_s3" "bucket" {
  bucket = "terraform-s3-bucket"
  acl = "private"

  tags = {
    Name = "My Bucket"
    Environment = "Test"
  }
}
```

However when I run `terraform apply` on the above code, I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid resource type

  on main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3" "bucket":
   1: resource "aws_s3" "bucket" {

The provider provider.aws does not support resource type "aws_s3".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no resource named `aws_s3`. The resource [you are looking](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html) for is `aws_s3_bucket`.